# Generating a UNIQUE random number to execute random images in express EJS (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
  <body>
<div><% for(var i=0;i<pictures.length;i++){ %>
    <img src="images\<%= Math.floor((Math.random() * pictures.length) + 1) %>.jpg">
<%}%>
</div>
```

Here, Math.random is executing 3 random images but NOT unique. How can I generate unique numbers so that the images execute uniquely ?

Comment: First of all "generating" uniqe number does not make any sense because it will never be unique. To make "almost" unique string you have to mix chars and numbers and it has to be pretty long

Comment: It will never be unique because Math.random is generating 3 random NOT unique numbers. What do u mean almost unique ? I want it to generate something like "1,2,3"/"2,3,1"/etc instead of "1,1,2", for example.

Comment: Might be helpful to know how your `pictures` array is structured exactly, since you might be able to simply shuffle the array instead of generating random numbers in a loop.

Comment: Yes check my comment on Dennington-bear's post, I'm using mySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't possible without an array to store your random numbers(If i haven't misunderstood the question). So essentially what you are doing is creating an array and storing the generated random numbers. Then if the numbers are 'unique' add them to the array. Then loop through the array construct a source string for the image tag and then just call the image tag with the constructed source.

```
    <% var arr = [] %>
    //<!-- Make the while loop the size you eg. how many images you want shown.
    // Here it is the length of the amount of pictures change it to suit your needs -->
        <% while(arr.length < pictures.length ){
            //<!-- Create your random number -->
            var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * pictures.length) + 1);
            //<!-- If the random number is not in the array -->
            if(arr.indexOf(randomNum) == -1){
                // Add the random number to the array
                arr.push(randomNum);
            }
        } %>
        <!-- Loop through the array -->
        <%arr.forEach(function(number){ %>
            <!-- Construct image source -->
            <% var source = "images/"+number+".jpg"; %>
            <!-- Create the image using the constructed source -->
            <img src=<%=source%>>
        <%});%>
```

Comment: I'm using MySQL to extract the numbers

Comment: What numbers? I don't understand so give me a bit more info and ill try help

Comment: I have a table called "pictures" with auto-incremented column called "pid" (picture id), and there are the numbered images inside the "images" folder (1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc)...

Comment: @CédricHadjian Yes thats what this does it generates an array of [1,2,3] where the elements are never the same(as per the question). Then it constructs a string based on the number to be used as a source e.g. `images/4.jpg`,`images/1.jpg`,`images/3.jpg`,`images/2.jpg`. If the source is different let me know and ill update the answer

Comment: Okay let me try. Thank you.

Comment: @CédricHadjian Ive updated my answer a few times due to copy&paste errors so make sure you have the up to date version

Comment: Oh god it WORKED. Thanks a million. :D

Comment: @CédricHadjian Accept the answer if you are happy and no problem

Comment: Done. Thanks again.